# What is "setindex! not defined" error in julia?

Tags: coding-style, julia, ijulia-notebook

When I run my code one error occurs with my code **setindex! not defined for WeakRefStrings.StringArray{String,1}**

CSV File [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zr3b.png).

```
using CSV
EVDdata =CSV.read(raw"wikipediaEVDdatesconverted.csv")
EVDdata[end-9:end,:]
```

And the Error Code is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPRog.png)

```
rows, cols = size(EVDdata)
for j =1:cols
    for i = 1:rows
        if !isdigit(string(EVDdata[i, j])[1])
            EVDdata[i,j] = 0
        end
    end
end
```

I am working with **Julia 1.4.1** on **Jupter Notebook**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setindex!(collection, item, inds...)` is the function that `colection[inds...] = item` gets lowered to. The error comes from the fact that `CSV.read` makes an immutable collection.

Answer (score 2):

As Oscar says in his answer, `setindex!` tries to mutate its arguments, i.e. change the contents of your column in place. When you do `CSV.read()`, by default immutable columns of type `CSV.Column` are returned. This is done for performance reason, as it means columns don't have to be copied after parsing.

To get around this, you can do two things:

1. Pass the keyword argument `CSV.read(raw"wikipediaEVDdatesconverted.csv", copycols = true)` - this will copy the columns and therefore make them mutable; or
2. Achieve the same by using `DataFrame((raw"wikipediaEVDdatesconverted.csv"))`

The second way is the preferred way as `CSV.read` will be deprecated in the `CSV.jl` package.

You can see that it's current implementation is basically doing the same thing I listed in (2) above in the source [here](https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl/blob/ac9fe2566daf8cb58045afef180b1241289f4916/src/CSV.jl#L43). Removing this method will allow `CSV.jl` not to depend on `DataFrames.jl` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be done this way

col1dt = Vector{Dates.DateTime}(undef, length(col1))

for v = 1:length(col1)
    col1dt[v] = Dates.DateTime(col1[v], "d-u-y")
end