# Set index! not defined for WeakRefStrings. SpringArray{String,1}

Tags: indexing, set, julia

i wanted to create a loop on a column in my IJulia and I came up with this error. Please what can I do to rectify it.

Here is my code:

```
for v=1:length(col1)
    col1[v] = Dates.DateTime(col1[v], "d-u-y")
end
```

And I got this error:

```
setindex! not defined for WeakRefStrings.StringArray{String,1}

Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String, ::Type{T} where T) at .\error.jl:42
 [2] error_if_canonical_setindex(::IndexLinear, ::WeakRefStrings.StringArray{String,1}, ::Int64) at .\abstractarray.jl:1081
 [3] setindex!(::WeakRefStrings.StringArray{String,1}, ::DateTime, ::Int64) at .\abstractarray.jl:1072
 [4] top-level scope at .\In[130]:2
```

I decided to try changing the code a little bit using:

```
for i in col1
       global col1[i] = Dates.DateTime(string.(col1[i]), "d-u-y")
end
```

Then I still got this error:

```
ArgumentError: invalid index: "4-Jul-2014" of type String

Stacktrace:
 [1] to_index(::String) at .\indices.jl:297
 [2] to_index(::WeakRefStrings.StringArray{String,1}, ::String) at .\indices.jl:274
 [3] to_indices at .\indices.jl:325 [inlined]
 [4] to_indices at .\indices.jl:322 [inlined]
 [5] getindex(::WeakRefStrings.StringArray{String,1}, ::String) at .\abstractarray.jl:980
 [6] top-level scope at .\In[136]:2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add the source code to your question contains the problem you describe? That will make it easier for our users to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate issues at play here. The first issue as that you likely read in some data using `CSV.read()`, which gives you an immutable set of columns. As they are immutable, `setindex!` (essentially changing the contents) is not allowed. A question on this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61995125/what-is-setindex-not-defined-error-in-julia).

The second issue is unrelated and is due to the fact that you are now iterating over the actual column `col1`, so that `i` is not an integer anymore, but takes the value of whatever is in `col1`, in your case a `WeakRefString`. So when you do `col1[i]`, `i` has the value `"4-Jul-2014"`, because that's the first value in the `col1` column.

In any case you don't need to loop here at all, but can simply rely on Julia's broadcasting syntax like so:

```
Date.(col1, DateFormat("d-u-y"))
```

The dot after `Date` broadcasts the `Date` constructor over each element of `col1`. Note also that you can just use `Date` rather than `DateTime` as based on the date that shows up in your error messages it looks like your data doesn't have a time attached to it.

Comment: Thank you Nils . It worked by using the Date broadcast.